# Handlebars js not rendering object array returned by mysql query (in nodejs server)

Tags: mysql, node.js, handlebars.js

I am using {{#each rows}} loop in a view, but the objects array that it is iterating through is not rendering.
The object array is displayed if I use res.send(rows), so the database is returning results.
When running this server on the cloud9 platform, the view renders with the table filled with the object attributes, but when I try running this server on my Amazon Web Server, the view renders but the #each loop does not render, in fact, when looking at the page source it is as though rows was not even received. But again, if I do a res.send(rows) the rows object array is displayed.
I would really appreciate any help at all.

//Here is the code in my server:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('./dbContentPool.js');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({defaultLayout:'main'});
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('port', 3000);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/Donors/business', function(req, res, next){
            mysql.pool.query('SELECT * FROM ' + 'business', function(err, rows, fields){

            if(err){

                    next(err);

                    return;

            }

            res.render('Donors/business/index', rows);

    });
});
```

//here is the code in my view called 'Donors/business/index':

```
    <h1>Donors</h1>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">

    <thead>

        <tr>

            <th>Name

            <th>Address

            <th>City

            <th>State

            <th>Zip

            <th>Specific Location</th>

        </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>

        {{#each rows}}

            <tr>

                <td>{{this.name}}

                <td>{{this.street_address}}

                <td>{{this.city}}

                <td>{{this.state}}

                <td>{{this.zip}}

                <td>{{this.specific_location}}

            </tr>

        {{/each}}

    </tbody>

</table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<form role="form" action="/Donors/business" method="POST">

    <fieldset>

        <legend>See Available Food From a Specific Donor:</legend>

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="Specific_donor">Pick a Specific Donor:</label>

                <select class="form-control" name="business_id" id="business_id">

                    <option>--Select Donor--</option>

                        {{#each businesses}}

                                <option value={{this.id}}>{{this.name}}</option>

                        {{/each}}

                </select>

            <input type="submit" id="entrySubmitABusiness" class="btn btn-primary">

    </fieldset>

</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
res.render('Donors/business/index', {rows: rows});
```

Comment: This fixed it, thank you so much!
Before posting my question, I had tried: res.render('Donors/business/index', {rows});
but I received an error: unexpected token. Again thank you so much!